# Book for Forefront Identity Manager 2010

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010

I can't believe it but I am not able to find a book for Forefront Identity Manager 2010.

I am looking for a Administrator's Guide or something like that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/forefront-identity-manager-resources.aspx#Books   (2 minutes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

- http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/fim-best-practices-volume-1-introduction-architecture-and-installation-of-forefront-identity-manager-2010/12917401 (this is the only book i recall)
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/forefront-identity-manager-resources.aspx (loads and loads of addional notes. Take a look at the Technical Libraries section)